# Interactive/dynamic grid cells

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, grid, touch

I'm trying to come up with a solution to generate a grid on-screen and have each cell interactive (simple click event). The best way to describe it would be dynamically building a 2D tile map by clicking cells.

I'm still very new to the mobile tools, so I may be missing something obvious. At first I assumed that I could use the Grid control, but I don't believe there is a way to trigger each cell individually. Perhaps I need to somehow fill each cell with something that can be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. You can just make a control clickable if you give it some color, eg:

```
    <Grid
        x:Name="ContentPanel"
        Background="LightCoral"
        Tap="ContentPanel_Tap">

        <TextBlock
            x:Name="posTb" />



    private void ContentPanel_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.GetPosition(ContentPanel);
        posTb.Text = pos.X + "," + pos.Y;
    }
```

With that you can determine the position you tapped and as such a cell in a grid, but you probably want to fill the grid with some content anyways, so you can just make that content clickable.